# Installed libraries are "missing" when Crosscompiling with buildroot toolchain

Tags: dependencies, cross-compiling, buildroot

I have a virtual machine (x86_64 architecture) running debian that I am setting up as a crosscompile environment for the armv7 platform. I use buildroot to build the toolchain for armv7, and that part works fine: `make menuconfig`, `make sdk`, copy out and extract the produced tarball with the arm-compilers.

However, the environment seems to be missing some dependencies.

For example, when trying to `./configure $CONFIGURE_FLAGS` for dbclient (the client portion of dropbear), I get the following error:

```
checking for deflate in -lz... no
configure: error: *** zlib missing - install first or check config.log ***
```

I use buildroot for most things, resulting in this file that i `source`:

```
SDK_PATH=$(dirname $(realpath "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"))
export "AR=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ar"
export "AS=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-as"
export "LD=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld"
export "NM=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-nm"
export "CC=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc"
export "GCC=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc"
export "CPP=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-cpp"
export "CXX=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-g++"
export "FC=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gfortran"
export "F77=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gfortran"
export "RANLIB=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ranlib"
export "READELF=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-readelf"
export "STRIP=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-strip"
export "OBJCOPY=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objcopy"
export "OBJDUMP=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objdump"
export "AR_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/ar"
export "AS_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/as"
export "CC_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/gcc"
export "GCC_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/gcc"
export "CXX_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/g++"
export "LD_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/ld"
export "CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-I$SDK_PATH/include"
export "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-O2 -I$SDK_PATH/include"
export "CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-O2 -I$SDK_PATH/include"
export "LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-L$SDK_PATH/lib -Wl,-rpath,$SDK_PATH/lib"
export "FCFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="
export "DEFAULT_ASSEMBLER=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-as"
export "DEFAULT_LINKER=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld"
export "CPPFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
export "CFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  "
export "CXXFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  "
export "LDFLAGS="
export "FCFLAGS= -Os "
export "FFLAGS= -Os "
export "PKG_CONFIG=$SDK_PATH/bin/pkg-config"
export "STAGING_DIR=$SDK_PATH/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/sysroot"
export "INTLTOOL_PERL=/usr/bin/perl"
export "CROSS_COMPILE=$SDK_PATH/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-"
export "CONFIGURE_FLAGS=--target=arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf --host=arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --program-prefix="
alias configure="./configure ${CONFIGURE_FLAGS}"
alias cmake="cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$SDK_PATH/share/buildroot/toolchainfile.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr"
export "PATH=$SDK_PATH/bin:$SDK_PATH/sbin:$PATH"
```

Everything seems fine and dandy, and the correct compilers are found as expected. As you can see, I have the toolchain from buildroot located in `/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/`. After sourcing, my `env` looks like this:

```
(snipped irrelevant stuff)
PKG_CONFIG=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/pkg-config
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-O2 -I/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/include
FCFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
AS_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/as
CFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  
STAGING_DIR=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/sysroot
INTLTOOL_PERL=/usr/bin/perl
CC=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc
READELF=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-readelf
XDG_SESSION_ID=70
USER=jarmund
CXXFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  
STRIP=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-strip
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-L/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/lib
OBJCOPY=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objcopy
PWD=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot
CONFIGURE_FLAGS=--target=arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf --host=arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --program-prefix=
F77=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gfortran
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
RANLIB=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ranlib
OBJDUMP=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objdump
AS=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-as
AR=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ar
FCFLAGS= -Os 
CC_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/gcc
CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-I/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/include
FC=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gfortran
NM=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-nm
CXX=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-g++
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-
FFLAGS= -Os 
CPPFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
GCC_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-O2 -I/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/include
LOGNAME=jarmund
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LDFLAGS=
CXX_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/g++
LD_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/ld
DEFAULT_LINKER=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld
PATH=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin:/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/sbin:/home/jarmund/bin:/home/jarmund/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/sandbox/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/share/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
GCC=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc
DEFAULT_ASSEMBLER=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-as
CPP=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-cpp
LD=/home/jarmund/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld
AR_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/ar
_=/usr/bin/env
```

The dev system does include zlib, as I get this message when I try to `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`:

```
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2).
```

It is worth noting that I have a different project with the same issue, but for libjson/json-c, which is also installed. So I believe that the issues are related, and that it is my cross-compilation environment that is missing something. Do I need to get these libraries for the arm platform somehow? Or do I somehow include the ones I already do have on my system?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you are running a virtual machine to do a cross compile? Can't you just create an Arm virtual machine and compile it with the "native" toolchain?

Comment: @AndreiTumbar because virtualbox is not an emulator, and as such does not emulate a CPU architecture, but instead relies on the actual CPU architecture of the host system. If I could emulate an ARM machine in its entirety, I would.

Comment: Maybe try using QEMU to compile a chroot'ed environment (this will emulate the arm instruction set). I would look at Gentoo documentation for cross-compilation: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Cross_build_environment